# Laravel 6 - validate unique, ignore on two conditions - same user and name. Also $this->id is null on update

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-validation

I have the following rule so far.

```php
$rules['name'] = [
    'required',
    'string',
    'min:3',
    'max:255',
    Rule::unique('user_templates', 'name')->ignore($this->id),
];
```

Users can create records, but all his records must have a unique name (other users can have records with the same name). How can I do this? Also, `$this->id` on update is always null. What am I doing wrong?

**Controller**

```php
public function update(UserTemplatesRequest $request, $slug)
{
    try {
        $model = UserTemplates::where('slug', XSS::clean($slug))
            ->firstOrFail();
    } catch (ModelNotFoundException $err) {
        return redirect()->action('UserTemplatesController@index');
    }

    $data = $request->validated();

    if ($model->updateTemplate(XSS::clean($data, ['file']), $request)) {
        $message = "There was an error, please try again";
        $action = 'index';
        $id = '';
    } else {
        $message = "Category Updated";
        $action = 'edit';
        $id = $model->id;
    }

    return redirect()->action("CategoriesController@{$action}", [$id])
        ->with('message', $message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your Rule you can try and use a where clause to narrow it down to one user and not whole project like:

```
      Rule::unique('user_templates', 'name')->where(function (Builder $query) {
            return $query->where(
                'user_id', '=', $this->user()->id;
        })
```

`user_id` is the column inside your `user_templates` table that works as a foreign key with your users table.

About `$this->id` it should be `$this->user()->id` to retrieve your user id